# Changing Data from an other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering what kind of query should I accept to allow my data to be updated. My models consists of client, interest, and a manager

```
Clients his has follow
id
name
email
password

Interest
id
description

manager
customer_id
interest_id
created_at
```

The goal of the manager his not to override old data in interest but just keep adding a new interest and refering to it.

```
The relationship his has follow
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :music_interest_managers
  has_many :music_interests, through => :music_interest_managers
end
class MusicInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :music_interest_managers
  has_many :clients, through => :music_interest_managers
end
class MusicInterestManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :music_interests
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Now to update the data from the customer controller i am not sure how would i do this
This is what i am thinking about:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
@manager = @client.manager.build(params[:manager])
@interest = @interest.manager.build(params[:interest])
```

Does this make sense? or i am dead wrong?

Update:

```
def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    @interest = @client.music_interests.build(params[:interest])

    if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        #sign_in @client
        redirect_to @client
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Or should i render a model view from interest to then apply the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
@interest = @client.music_interests.build(params[:interest])
```

should work - try it out in the console!

Comment: Not sure how to apply it!! I have updated my client to allow to indicate how can it be done?

Comment: as I said - start the console with rails console and try out if the steps are doing what you want!